# python numpy csv header in column not row

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I have a script which produces a 15x1096 array of data using

```
np.savetxt("model_concentrations.csv", model_con, header="rows:','.join(sources), delimiter=",")
```

Each of the 15 rows corresponds to a source of emissions, while each column is 1 day over 3 years. If at all possible I would like to have a 'header' in column 1 which states the emssion source. When i use the option "header='source1,source2,...'" these labels get placed in the first row (like expected). ie.

```
2per         3rd_pvd    3rd_unpvd   4rai_rd     4rai_yd      5rmo        6hea
2.44E+00    2.12E+00    1.76E+00    1.33E+00    6.15E-01    3.26E-01    2.29E+00 ...
1.13E-01    4.21E-02    3.79E-02    2.05E-02    1.51E-02    2.29E-02    2.36E-01 ...
```

My question is, is there a way to inverse the header so the csv appears like this:

```
2per        7.77E+00    8.48E-01 ...
3rd_pvd     1.86E-01    3.62E-02 ...
3rd_unpvd   1.04E+00    2.65E-01 ...
4rai_rd     8.68E-02    2.88E-02 ...
4rai_yd     1.94E-01    8.58E-02 ...
5rmo        7.71E-01    1.17E-01 ...
6hea        1.07E+01    2.71E+00 ...
...
```

Comment: Yes. Load your array into a pandas dataframe and call df.transpose()

Comment: You could write your own file.  Start with printing your data line by line with the right format.  Don't be afraid to the iterate over rows or columns of the array.  That's what `savetxt` does.

Comment: @BraydenNilson Could you put a part from your txt file ? I need to make a script with numpy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Labels for rows and columns is one of main reasons for the existence of pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

# Assemble your source labels in a list
sources = ['2per', '3rd_pvd', '3rd_unpvd', '4rai_rd',
           '4rai_yd', '5rmo', '6hea', ...]

# Create a pandas DataFrame wrapping your numpy array
df = pd.DataFrame(model_con, index=sources)

# Saving it a .csv file writes the index too
df.to_csv('model_concentrations.csv', header=None)
```

Comment: @Brayden Nilson if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.